# Отправка сообщения на все сервера в определённый канал с id из базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я хотел на discord.py сделать бота для авто партнёрств, всё что нужно - я сделал. Осталось лишь сделать отправку сообщений на все сервера в определённый канал, я делал всё что мог. Но бот только и делал, что кидал текст пиара лишь в один канал на сервере где прописана команда.

```
@client.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    chanid = collection.find_one()["chan"]
    chanid = int(chanid)
    text = collection.find_one()["descript"]    
    baner = collection.find_one()["banner"]
    channl = client.get_channel(chanid)
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    yes = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Успешная рассылка.',
        description = 'Ваше объявление рассылается по партнёрским серверам, ожидайте.',
        color = 0x00ccd4
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=yes)

    for guild in client.guilds:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f'{ctx.guild.name}',
            description = f'{text}\n** | Ccылка на сервер**\n**✅ | [Присоединиться]({invite})**\n\n** | Владелец сервера:** {ctx.guild.owner}\n** | Количество участников:** {ctx.guild.member_count}\n`ID: {ctx.guild.id}`',
            color = 0x00ccd4
        )
        embed.set_image(url=baner)
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if channl != None:
                await channl.send(embed=embed)

            else:

                em = discord.Embed(
                    title = 'Рассылка запрещается!',
                    description = 'Вы не настроили канал для отображения партнёрских объявлений!',
                    color = 0x00ccd4
                )
                await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    # объявляем переменные
    text = collection.find_one()["descript"]
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    banner = collection.find_one()["banner"]

    yes = discord.Embed(title='Успешная рассылка.', description='Ваше объявление рассылается по партнёрским серверам, ожидайте.', color=0x00ccd4)
    await ctx.send(embed=yes)

    for guild in client.guilds:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.guild.name}', description=f'{text}\n** | Ccылка на сервер**\n**✅ | [Присоединиться]({invite})**\n\n** | Владелец сервера:** {ctx.guild.owner}\n** | Количество участников:** {ctx.guild.member_count}\n`ID: {ctx.guild.id}`', color=0x00ccd4)
        embed.set_image(url=banner)

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Ваш код работает так:

1. Получение переменных из БД
2. Отправка embed во **все** каналы на **всех** серверах, где есть бот.

Вот пример как сделать отправку на **все** сервера, где есть бот в определённый канал:

```
import random

@client.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    # объявляем переменные
    text = collection.find_one()["descript"]
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    banner = collection.find_one()["banner"]

    yes = discord.Embed(title='Успешная рассылка.', description='Ваше объявление рассылается по партнёрским серверам, ожидайте.', color=0x00ccd4)
    await ctx.send(embed=yes)

    for guild in client.guilds:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.guild.name}', description=f'{text}\n** | Ccылка на сервер**\n**✅ | [Присоединиться]({invite})**\n\n** | Владелец сервера:** {ctx.guild.owner}\n** | Количество участников:** {ctx.guild.member_count}\n`ID: {ctx.guild.id}`', color=0x00ccd4)
        embed.set_image(url=banner)

        # здесь Вам необходимо сделать запрос к Вашей БД, в котором нужно получить ID партнёрского канала для сервера guild
        channel_id =  # ЗДЕСЬ ЗАПРОС К БД!
        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            em = discord.Embed(title='Рассылка запрещается!', description='Вы не настроили канал для отображения партнёрских объявлений!', color=0x00ccd4)
            await random(guild.text_channels).send(embed=em) # отправит сообщение в рандомный канал
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам

Comment: Если это помогло, то поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку